# Fax virtual machines for testing

Tags: java, simulator, fax

I have to implement a fax functionality in my application which is developed in java. So I need a java fax API, and luckily I found fax4j. But the problem is that I do not have any fax machine or fax printer, so I wish that is there could be a virtual fax machine/ fax machine simulator so that I can test my faxing code with it? Kindly guide me in that direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Consider a 'fax to email' service like http://www.freefaxtoemail.net/ - looks like it's free too :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using windows, the API would work even without a fax connected to your PC.
the fax would be submitted to the queue, but there it would fail.
That means your code would work just fine, no issues and if you listen to fax monitor events, you would see that the fax status changes to error after a while when the queue processes it and finds there is no line.
if you are using a different OS, there are many other ways to test, just need to understand what you are doing.

you can also post on the official fax4j [forums](http://sourceforge.net/p/fax4j/discussion/Support/)